# Every time I open the Software Center it hangs then closes it self. I got this error log from the terminal

Tags: 13.04, software-center

```
** (software-center:6812): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-CX8KaNsILp: Connection refused
2013-10-23 22:48:44,222 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-10-23 22:48:57,143 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-10-23 22:48:57,279 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2013-10-23 22:48:57,526 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2013-10-23 22:48:57,526 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2013-10-23 22:49:00,349 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2013-10-23 22:49:45,431 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py', 410, '_introspect_error_handler')'
2013-10-23 22:49:45,430 - dbus.proxies - ERROR - Introspect error on com.ubuntu.sso:/com/ubuntu/sso/credentials: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
2013-10-23 22:51:44,641 - softwarecenter.db.utils - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 183, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1375, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1313, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 150, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 240, in init_view
    vm.display_page(self, self.Pages.LOBBY, self.state)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 183, in display_page
    pane.enter_page(page, view_state)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 637, in enter_page
    self.display_lobby_page(state)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 652, in display_lobby_page
    self._clear_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 559, in _clear_search
    self.searchentry.clear_with_no_signal()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/searchentry.py", line 120, in clear_with_no_signal
    self.handler_block(self._handler_changed)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GObject.py", line 454, in signal_handler_block
    GObjectModule.signal_handler_block(_get_instance_for_signal(obj), handler_id)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 113, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: argument instance: Expected GObject.Object, but got PyCObject
```

Comment: the title should be a title. The body should contain more than just an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try with re-installing the software center.

Open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

Then try again.